# How can I make this RNG have a size?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to make a NPM package. It does generate random numbers between the designed range, if the user specifies a minimum and maximum value. What I want though, is to also have a control to make it generate number strings(?).

So if the user inside the app specified:

```
min = 0;
max = 21;
size = 23;
token(min, max, size);
```

It would specify a 23-char long number string(?) with random numbers between 0 and 21. Is it possible to do so?

The package code is:

```
module.exports = function token(min, max, size) {
    var size = size || 128;
    var newToken = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
    return (newToken[size]);
};
```

I tried many things, but it ends returning either NaN or undefined.

Comment: Your `newToken` is not an array but a number, why are you calling `newToken[size]`?

Comment: It's possible to do pretty much anything but you'd need to clear up *what* is it you want. "*a 23-char long number string(?) with random numbers between 0 and 21*" seems very vague. Do you want this to be *up to* 23 characters long or only ever 23 characters? What does it mean to use numbers between 0 and 21? Do you want, say, `35` to not appear anywhere in the number? Although you can produce `3` and `5` as two neighbouring characters, but, say, the next thing generated could be `12` for `3512` in total?

Comment: So basically if the user specified the token package like I did, it would generate a 23 number long token, with random numbers in between 0 and 21. That means 0, 1, 2, and so on until 21. And I was just testing @dporechny

Comment: Why don't you debug your function and see what `newToken` is?

Comment: @barbsan newToken there will generate a random number in between the user-specified range. I just want to add a max character control. It's perfectly working without the size.

Comment: But you don't build any string in your function. You could [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) string, but you have to build it first

Comment: But how does slice work? How can it impact the size of the generated number?

Comment: @andremont0101 So actually you want to return an array (a list) of multiple individual numbers? Not a string?

Answer (score 0):

You already generate a number between `min` and `max`, so one way to do it is to make a loop until you can return your pseudo random number (as a string).

Example:

```js
function token(min, max, size) {
  var size = size || 128;
  var newToken = '';
  while (newToken.length < size) {
    newToken += Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  return newToken.substring(0, size);
};
  
var res = token(0, 21, 23);
console.log(res);
console.log(res.length);
```

Here I'm using an ugly way to return precisely the number at the specified length with the help of [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), in case the last generated number exceed the desired size, it doesn't matter to much anyway because, as I have already said, it's not a very precise algorythm.

I'm sure you could find a better way to do it.

Comment: Wow, that works just fine! I will add that as a number-only option to my package, since I found out a way myself to make a token with letters, numbers and symbols. Almost like you did, with an array containing all of the letters/numbers/characters the token can use. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to figure as an option in your number package.